# Как добавить смену изображения при наведении курсора в TagCanvas

Tags: javascript

Как добавить смену изображения при наведении курсора в [TagCanvas](http://www.goat1000.com/tagcanvas.php)?

Проблема такова, есть облако тегов в картинках, мне нужно что-бы при наведении на картинку она менялась.
Пробывал вот так, не срабатывает.

```html
  <body style="background-image:url(http:cloud/images/blue.jpg)">
<div style="text-align:center" id="myCanvasContainer">
  <canvas style="background-image:url(http:cloud/images/blue.jpg)" width="1100" height="800" id="myCanvas" >
  </canvas>
</div>
<div id="tags">
<ul id="tags">
<li>
 <li><a  id="imagesR" ><img id="img" src="images/water.jpg" onmouseout="this.src='images/water.jpg'"onmouseover="this.src='images/fire.jpg'">Text inside</a></li>
  <li><a  id="imagesR" ><img id="img2" src="images/water.jpg" onmouseout="this.src='images/water.jpg'" onmouseover="this.src='images/fire.jpg'">Text inside</a></li>

</ul>
```

```js
  < script type = "text/javascript" >
    window.onload = function() {
      try {
        TagCanvas.Start('myCanvas', 'tags', {
          textColour: '#ff4500',
          bgColour: '#ff4500',
          outlineColour: '#ff4500',
          reverse: true,
          depth: 0.8,
          maxSpeed: 0.1,
          onmouseout,
          onmouseover
        });
      } catch (e) {
        // something went wrong, hide the canvas container
        document.getElementById('myCanvasContainer').style.display = 'none';
      }
    }; < /script>
```

```css
<style> #tags {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 500px;
  left: -900px;
}
</style>
```

Пробывал еще добавить через id hover css, тоже не срабатывает.

Comment: Вы сами что то пробовали?

Comment: Пробывал через onmouseover, пробывал через css hover.

Comment: попробуйте проанализировать function tpu(s) {
 document.getElementById('sout').innerHTML = s.innerHTML;  return false; }

Comment: Я Вас не совсем понял, Вы предлагаете реализовать в  mouseout, innerHTML? Или добавить новое событие?

Comment: Предлагаю добавить новое событие на основе этой.

Comment: Тогда я вообще запутался, какое событие добавить, если onmouse не работает?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Ну в примере вроде все работает у Вас?

Comment: Не совсем так. Пример это без подгрузки tangvas.js, тоесть в принципе без него работать не будет облаков тегов, значит и смена картинок ни к чему)